# Any Advice on how to make this CNN training faster?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have been training a Neural Network for recognizing the differences between a paper with handwriting and a paper with Drawings, My images are all in (3508, 2480) size and I'm using a CNN for the task, the problem is that it is taking ages to train, I have 30,000 data belonging to 2 classes which are separated into validation and training, so I have:

- 13650 Images of Handwritten Paragraphs for training
- 13650 Images of Drawings for training
- 1350 Images of Drawings for validation
- 1250 Images of Drawings for validation

If you want to see my architecture here it is my

[image: summary()]

And here is my code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

```py
l0 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (60,60), activation='relu', input_shape=(438, 310, 1), name='input')
l1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.3)
l2 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
l3 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),padding='same')

l12 = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()

l16 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')
l17 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.5)
l18 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()

l22 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='output')
```

```py
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
trdata = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)
traindata = trdata.flow_from_directory("/content/drive/MyDrive/Sae/TesisProgra/DataSets/ParagraphsVsDrawings/Paste/0_Final/Training",target_size=(438, 310), color_mode="grayscale", batch_size=250)
valdata = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)
validationdata = valdata.flow_from_directory("/content/drive/MyDrive/Sae/TesisProgra/DataSets/ParagraphsVsDrawings/Paste/0_Final/Validation",target_size=(438, 310), color_mode="grayscale", batch_size=250)
```

```py
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("ParagraphsVsDrawings.h5", monitor='val_accuracy', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, save_freq='epoch', mode='auto')
history = model.fit(traindata, validation_data=validationdata, validation_steps=10,epochs=20, verbose=True, callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

**I´m using Google Colab PRO for the training with TPU and Big RAM options activated**

I have trained CNN before, but they trained really fast, I don´t know if it's for my images being to big maybe I could try resizing them with pillow, but I'm really lost at this point, I have been waiting 12 hours and It's still on first epoch

Comment: From a basic overview, I can tell is that your batch size is huge. Consider to lower it down. Usually, I use batch sizes of 15-30 or so. And also the image shape is a matter of concern here. If possible please reduce it.
Another thing is that I have noticed is you're using TPU. AFAIK, TPU's need to be handled differently in code. For this trivial CNN, you should use GPU.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I did a lot of the things you recommended and got the time reduced from  336 to 36 hours aprox, but it is still a lot to proces, so maybe it would be because of my dataset being too large? I got 37,937 parameters at last and changed to GPU, changed batch size to 32 and it works faster, but not as I was used to

Comment: 37k+ params are just fine with ConvNets. In fact, I use free colab with around 10 Million params and it takes only a few hours to train with early stopping. However, one last thing is you really should consider adding a few Conv layers along with max-pooling and dropouts if needed to lower the training time. Thanks!

Comment: Thx a lot for the advice, I made 4 layers of Conv2D with their respective BatchNormalization, Pooling and dropout layers, now my accuracy is remaining constant but that´s another problem, the CNN is training fast now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your kernel size, 60 by 60, is quite big. Try 3 by 3 kernel or 5 by 5 kernel. It doesn't seem that image size is the problem since you are resizing from (3508, 2480) to (438, 310).

Also notice that the number of weights you have is very, very large. It is around 24 million. This is because you are flattening a (189, 125, 32) shape array and then your next layer (Dense) has 32 units, so 189 * 125 * 32 * 32 weights for that layer. That will take very, very long to train.

Try to add one or two more conv layers + pooling layers so that the number of weights when flattened is manageable.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who has my same problem here it is my final code of the CNN architecture, which runs much faster than the one I had previusly, credits to users [Afif Al Mamun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7092004/afif-al-mamun) and [ntlarry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14171819/ntlarry)

[ModelSummary()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndJsL.png)

**Code**

```py
lc0 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu', input_shape=(438, 310, 1), name='input')
lc1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.3)
lc2 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
lc3 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),padding='same')

lc4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu')
lc5 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.3)
lc6 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
lc7 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),padding='same')

lc8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu')
lc9 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.3)
lc10 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
lc11 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(4,80),padding='same')

lc8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, (3,3), activation='relu')
lc9 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.3)
lc10 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
lc11 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(4,80),padding='same')

lf = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()

ld1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')
ld2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.5)
ld3 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()

lfinal = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='output')
```

```py
model = tf.keras.Sequential([lc0,lc1,lc2,lc3,lc8,lc9,lc10,lc11,lf,ld1,ld2,ld3,lfinal], name="ParagraphIdentification")
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr = 0.001), metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Comment: I would also like to comment that usually it is convention to increase the number of filters as you get deeper (e.g. 6 -> 12 -> 16 -> 32 instead of 64 -> 32 -> 16 -> 8), even if that will increase the number of parameters